# Print "N NE E SE S SW W NW"

Tags: code-golf, string, kolmogorov-complexity

This seems almost trivial, but since after some effort I was not able to beat the literal solution in J, I thought it might make a decent challenge (though, to be clear, this is not a J-specific challenge).

Title says it all.  You simply need to write a program, or function (taking no arguments) that returns or prints:

```
N NE E SE S SW W NW
```

You may use newlines in place of spaces.

A no-argument function returning an array of strings such as

```
['N', 'NE', 'E', 'SE', 'S', 'SW', 'W', 'NW']
```

is also acceptable.

The letters may be upper or lower case, but may not be mixed.

Comment: Perhaps allowing them to be output in any order would be slightly more interesting

Comment: @JoKing Sure, I'll remove that.  Honestly, I didn't expect anyone to submit answers that used the full literal value -- that's not in the spirit of the question.  As I state, it came up because I _wasn't_ able to beat the literal in J, despite the string having regularity and structure of a sort.  The whole point is to exploit that regularity to beat a literal answer.  Bad on me for not being more explicit.  Allowing them any order defeats that as well, so I don't want to make that change.

Comment: Well, even though everything's been a literal, compressed literal, or base conversion, I do still like the idea here... maybe a new challenge with the cardinal directions spelled out could do better? I feel like raw dictionary compression, or maybe base conversion with dictionary compression, would probably end up being the shortest, but at least languages without good compression tools would be able to go algorithmic with it.

Comment: @UnrelatedString The most promising idea I've had is to note that the directions correspond to *i* raised to the powers `0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5`.  Unfortunately the J code required to then map those results into letters ended up being more expensive than a literal.

Comment: Ah, smart! I wonder if the mapping might work better for the Gaussian integers `1, 1+i, i, -1+i, -1, -1-i, -i, 1-i` so you've got one real or imaginary part per cardinal direction instead of two. It's probably harder to generate those though, unless there's some way you could round those powers of *i* away from 0? I don't know how easy or hard that would be in J, but it's an idea.

Comment: If returning an array of strings, are spaces acceptable in those strings? e.g. `[' W', ' E', 'N ', 'NW', 'NE', 'S ', 'SW', 'SE']`

Comment: May we have additional spaces between directions, e.g. `N  NE  E  SE  S  SW  W  NW`?

Comment: @Adám Sorry on further consideration I think that should be illegal

Comment: @Sok Sorry yours isn’t allowed either (but nice answer if it has been)

Comment: It feels like entries should also show the naive "echo this string" version in their language for comparison, and judging be done on the % shortened?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
＞X½+Ｔ）ＡuS{⁹‟
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjFFWCVCRCsldUZGMzQldUZGMDkldUZGMjF1UyU3QiV1MjA3OSV1MjAxRg__,v=8)

The string, simply compressed.

Comment: Can you explain how this works in a little more detail?

Comment: @Dillanm there isn't much more to say - Canvas has a built-in compressor (should be accessible with ctrl+o → string compress) that, here, simply stores the characters needed (`"NESW "`) and then in base-5 stores the individual characters.

Answer (score 59):

## bash (24 bytes)

using brace expansion

```
echo N {N,,S}E S {S,,N}W
```

is the same length as hard coding

```
echo N NE E SE S SW W NW
```

however it becomes more interesting when outputing more points of the compass

```
echo N NNE NE ENE E ESE SE SSE S SSW SW WSW W WNW NW NNW
```

brace expansion

```
echo N {{N,,E}N,,{E,,S}S}E S {{S,,W}S,,{W,,N}N}W
```

otherwise if order could be changed, (17 bytes), the trick is that without quotes the empy string parameter disappears

```
echo {N,,S}{W,,E}
```

Comment: That is interesting, I didn't know that you could have empty position is the brace expression!

Comment: @flawr Useful when chrooting: `mount -t proc{,,}`

Comment: Or `cp file{,.bak}`

Answer (score 48):

## [Mornington Crescent](https://github.com/padarom/esoterpret), <s>4395</s> 3823 bytes

```
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Parsons Green
Take District Line to Paddington
Take Bakerloo Line to North Wembley
Take Bakerloo Line to Charing Cross
Take Bakerloo Line to Charing Cross
Take Bakerloo Line to Charing Cross
Take Bakerloo Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take Circle Line to Barbican
Take Circle Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Aldgate
Take Circle Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Charing Cross
Take Bakerloo Line to Charing Cross
Take Bakerloo Line to Charing Cross
Take Bakerloo Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take Circle Line to Bayswater
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take Circle Line to Baker Street
Take Circle Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Embankment
Take Northern Line to Stockwell
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take Circle Line to Farringdon
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take Circle Line to Blackfriars
Take Circle Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Moorgate
Take Northern Line to Waterloo
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take Circle Line to Westminster
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take Circle Line to Tower Hill
Take Circle Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Edgware Road
Take Circle Line to Liverpool Street
Take Central Line to Mile End
Take District Line to Victoria
Take Victoria Line to Seven Sisters
Take Victoria Line to Victoria
Take Circle Line to Victoria
Take District Line to Mile End
Take District Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Bank
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Barbican
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Bayswater
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Baker Street
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Farringdon
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Embankment
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Blackfriars
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Moorgate
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Westminster
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Tower Hill
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Aldgate
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Edgware Road
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Bank
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3VfBbsIwDL3vK/ID@4iVsXGAaVrROIfWg6hJPDkRFV/PAohWLaSh7YY6LpWiZzvOs53XKCQt9MqifkwITALa7nZzngF7Q7JrIM2mQgOzyCKus4cD9CyMJZHYAnrnZFAb9koA2muTpsedjgaR@5BELAwOG7IFqKWErcdmtObkgrARoTG3t2ngZCQokVAAE64UkFHCri/idTZaukecliLh2gN6knqS6YpbuIiN1dK5KVf/e6c@4luTOxqoo7fLlcXWdbptx36d4bMTxRaTLAcpPfg1rNzSpnMFXjjtg6ddm1/yJPsi4S6ddhWYIVI5AGfnWeybwrXhvdO/AGOV0KbrCMwxdyMwEadGvXoA0lXOCdgH8vSiwVRsgL4RZXW@3MQQl2UVhXMZ69SjM59uga45jvBpVQ4ZbECzWOxPbzw21RC1JKvg2faB7LzklMD9Nl5A9AJwo@b1Dd0kCf1i/zUpATkacvIBHegXvC63/6moAYEbcu5Vjf3V0CHdGjItAc0ccupNr4aeIxr6IQhefu3FdFY8eJ3GnR68Pw)

Since it's a bit much to expect you to read all that, let me give a quick overview of my approach. The main idea is to store 3 copies of the characters `N`,`E`,`S`,`W` at various stations on the Circle line, via Bank - Hammersmith. These characters are constructed from the start of a station name at Charing Cross. Then, construct   from the middle of a well-chosen station name using Mile End and Charing Cross, and store it at Bank so that it can be collected at Hammersmith in the concatenation. Finally, concatenate the characters one by one at Paddington, copying them again via Bank - Hammersmith if they are need to be reused later.

---

I think the current solution is fairly close to optimal with this strategy, at least in terms of number of stations visited: just 2 times I used a station *only* for transit:

1. to get to Seven Sisters (via Victoria station)
2. and to get back to Mornington Crescent (via Bank).

All other station visits were, if I didn't forget one, either storing/retrieving something useful or (part of) using the stations ability.

As for the line lengths, I've tried to pick the shortest names on Circle Line, but there may be a minor improvement there. It's possible that storing something on District can shave off a few bytes.

Comment: Two ideas to golf this some more: 1. take 'NE', 'SW', 'NW', 'SE' from a single station (Using e.g. `Ne`asden, `Sw`iss Cottage, Acton To`wn` and Mansion Hou`se`) 2. Try to exploit the fact that Paddington makes it easier to concatenate ` W ` rather than `W `. This does require some more overhead to 'refresh' Paddington, so it may not gain anything.

Comment: Does this use Dollis Hill loop rules? If so, I think it can be improved by use of an Argyle Street parabola, and maybe even a slightly modified version of the Webb-Ellis protocol.

Answer (score 30):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 19 bytes

```php
N NE E SE S SW W NW
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fT8HPVcFVIRiIFILDFcIV/ML//wcA)

Getting this out of the way. Someone will do it eventually.

Comment: Also works for HTML+JS.

Comment: Polyglot with ///.

Answer (score 27):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), <s>142</s> <s>139</s> <s>131</s> 119 bytes

```
++++++++++[>+++>+++++++>++++++++>+++++++++<<<<-]>>>--.<<++.>>.<-.<.>.<.>>+++++.<.<.>>.<<.>>.>---.<<<.>>>.<<<.>>-----.>.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fGw6i7YCEHZQDoxEMbRsg0I21s7PT1dWzsdHW1rOz07MBMvXsQBiiDsiyAYuDSaBKkFIQ2w5K64IAUMf//wA)

Simply loops 10 times to fill the cells with 30, 70, 80 and 90 then steps backward and forwards and adjusts the cell values to print out the required characters. Not much different from the standard "Hello world!".

Comment: Lol I've never understood how anyone can "golf" these obscure languages.  Its hard enough to understand what the code does in the first place (this is said coming from C++ / Java background)

Comment: @mackycheese21 what? C++ didn't teach you to love pointer manipulation?

Comment: brainfuck might be esoteric, but I sure wouldn't call it obscure

Comment: @candied_orange C++ taught me to hate pointer manipulation and run away whenever someone mentioned std::   :)

Comment: @UnrelatedString obscure, no. Obtuse, yes.

Comment: check out my answer with 118 :)

Answer (score 15):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 204 bytes

```
((((((((((((((((()()()){}()){}){}())){}{}))<([([][]){}()]{})(([][]){}[])>)<([][]
()())>)[[]]()())<([]()()())>)<((([]())[][]){}[][()])>)<([][()()])>[[]()])<([][((
)()){}])>)((()()())){}{})<((()()()()()){})>)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU5BDoAgDPvOduAHhI8sO6CJidF48Gp8@@xgcBCSspZ26XLX/UrbWQ8z@h/2y8/boL9AjJxJSFS0iQqFBgUU/wZr6cIi2kdXY6dbqFGeOcGmkXUTiLhDQ4oy7pndep08eFjgMLO0fg)

Comment: Points deducted for wrapping.

Answer (score 14):

## [MarioLANG](https://github.com/tomsmeding/MarioLANG), <strike>249</strike> 221 bytes

```
+
+
+
+
+
+
+
+
+  ((+++++++++)))<
+>==============="
)++++++++)+++((-[!)--.)++.(.---------.).(.).)++.((.).).(.).++++.(.).(.(+++++++++.))
=================#================================================================.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syszPScxL//9fmwsNKihoaGjDgKampg2Xtp0tKlDi0oQrAGINDd1oRU1dXT0gR09DTxcG9DSBPE2IKJgB5oJ0gRkaegh79DQ1uWzRgbIthUDv/38A)

Answer (score 13):

## Excel Formula, <s>59</s> 57 bytes

The following should be entered as an array formula (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```
=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,{14,369,5,499,19,517,23,387},4),1,)
```

After entering the formula as an array formula, highlight it in the formula bar and evaluate it using <kbd>F9</kbd> to return the result, for example:

Before:
[image: Before formula evaluation]

After:
[image: Before formula evaluation]

### How it works

The `ADDRESS` function returns a string representing a reference based on two parameters, `row` and `col`. The third parameter controls what type of reference is returned, an absolute or relative reference. For example, `=ADDRESS(1,2,4)` returns `"B1"`.

We can supply an array to `ADDRESS` and use it as an array formula to return multiple results, for example `=ADDRESS(1,{1,2,3},4)` returns `"A1","B1","C1"`.

Therefore, in my answer, the array supplied to `ADDRESS` are just the column numbers relating to the required compass points, e.g. Column 14 is column `N`, Column 369 is column `NE`.

However, we are not finished here since all the returned references have the row included, for example, `N1`, `NE1`. Therefore, we simply use `SUBSTITUTE` to remove the `1` from all references.

Comment: Would `=IF(1,"N NE E SE S SW W NW")` be valid?

Comment: @squid Yes it would indeed! However, I was going for an alternative which didn't require the string to be quoted verbatim.

Comment: How does this work?

Comment: @anatolyg I've added an explanation section, hope it's understandable.

Comment: the CSE keystrokes are no longer as of Excel 2021; also the poster has removed the requirement that output be in order, so you may be able something along the lines of `={"","N","S"}&{"";"E";"W"}` now

Answer (score 11):

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), <s>188</s> 183 bytes

*-5 thanks to squid*

```
iiissdddc{ddddd}iiiicdddd{iiiii}c{d}ic{dddd}iiicddd{iiii}c{dddd}iiic{iiiii}ic{d}ddddc{dddd}iiic{iiiii}ic{ddddd}dci{iiiii}ciiiic{ddddd}dddddciiiii{iiiii}c{ddddd}dddddcdddd{iiiii}c{i}dc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7LEYBACEMrsihno2POHBlqR8DFHyfIgwRsK3bKsbiTFAEwFFkWM0d2mh0tdOMFbSJt0NpczTXD7fVHpWGwjSup5Tor8OS@yOchhov7CQ)

Comment: `{i}dc` at the end for [183](https://tio.run/##XY7LEYBACEMrsihno2POHBlqR8DFHyfIgwRsK3bKsbiTFAEwFFkWM0d2mh0tdOMFbSJt0NpczTXD7fVHpWGwjSup5Tor8OS@yOchhov7CQ "Deadfish~ – Try It Online")

Answer (score 10):

## [Triangularity](https://github.com/Mr-Xcoder/Triangularity), 71 bytes

```
..... .....
...."W"....
..."W N"...
.." SW "+..
." SE S"++.
"N NE E"+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLMosqfz/Xw8EFMAkF4hQCleCsZXCFfyUIGwlheBwBSVtEBvIdFUIVtLW1uNS8lPwc1VwVdJWUPj/HwA)

There are two spaces on the last line to hit the byte count Triangularity requires.

Answer (score 9):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 117 bytes

```
+++++[>++++++>+>+++>>++++>+++++<<<<<<-]>++[>++>++>+>++>++[<]>-]>>-.>.<.<.>>.<<.>>.>-.<<<.>>.>.<.>.>--.<<.>>.<<.<.>>>.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LUpJCoAwDHxQSF4Q5iPSgy0IIngQ@v6YbQKZdX7n/V57PWYUOJBEoBBA6YAmeKBG6E1YHfAcLBD1g1N@T7RVxO65G60dxOwH)

This code will first create the characters "EN SW" into the memory and then move back and forth to print them. The space is in the middle, because it is printed most often. N and S and W and E never appear together so they are on opposite sides of the memory.
For optimization some of the final decrements happen during the output phase.

Comment: OK, that's a cool answer. Guess you beat me on this one. +1 for -1 :-)

Comment: BTW, forgot to say, welcome to the Code Golf site. Looking forward to competing with you in the future ☺

Comment: Welcome! Consider adding an explanation or a link to an online interpreter for the program. See other answers for examples. Short code-only answers tend to get automatically flagged as low-quality.

Comment: Thanks, I can add a explanation of my code. I will also try to understand how the online links work.

Comment: @Helena For the link you can check out the "Try it Online" link on my answer. If you paste your code in and run it you can then click on the link icon and get a perfectly formatted code golf answer that you can simply copy and paste here. Works like magic and supports many languages. Well worth a try.

Answer (score 8):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 14 bytes

```
”{⊟“�_Ｚn↖⦄ＲüΦ≦
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvREPJT8HPVcFVIRiIFILDFcIV/MKVNK3///@vW5YDAA) Link is to verbose version of code... which is just the string to be printed, as the auto-deverbosifier takes care of the string compression.

Printing the string uncompressed takes 19 bytes, since Charcoal prints printable ASCII literally. The best algorithmic answer I could come up with unfortunately takes 20 bytes:

```
Ｅ⁸ΦSNWE›³﹪⁻﹪⁺⁵×⁶μχι⁸
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM3sUDDQkfBLTOnJLVIQynYL9xVSUfBvSg1EcQ31lHwzU8pzcnX8M3MKy3WgHICcoBsUx2FkMzc1GINMx2FXE1NHQVDAyCRCcQWmiBg/f//f92yHAA) Outputs using array format (would cost two bytes to join the elements on spaces). Works by noticing that the letters of the string `SNWE` are used only when the current outer index equals or is 1 away (modulo 8) in either direction from the corresponding element of the list of indices `4,0,6,2`.

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>62</s> <s>61</s> <s>58</s> 53 bytes

```python
i=8
while i:print'NESESWNW'[~i+(i==4):][:1+i%2],;i-=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PWgqs8IzMnVSHTqqAoM69E3c812DU43C9cPbouU1sj09bWRNMqNtrKUDtT1ShWxzpT19bw/38A)

Not great, but at least not a plain print..

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>16</s>  15 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
“¤œỵpq⁵’ṃ“NESW
```

A full program printing the text

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5xDS45Ofrh7a0Hho8atjxpmPtzZDBT0cw0OV/j/HwA)**

---

16...

```
“¥Þ¡¦¢¬£æ‘ṃ“¡ɱ⁻»
```

A niladic Link which yields a list of lists of (lowercase) characters.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATEAzv9qZWxsef//4oCcwqXDnsKhwqbCosKswqPDpuKAmOG5g@KAnMKhybHigbvCu//Dh0v/)**

---

Alternative 15 as a niladic Link which yields a list of (lowercase) characters (with spaces): `“¡XÇŀqỵÑ’ṃ“¡⁴ṁ»`.

Answer (score 6):

## Commodore BASIC (TheC64Mini, C64, C128, VIC-20 etc.) 28 Tokenized BASIC bytes used

```
 0 PRINT"N NE E SE S SW W NW
```

In Commodore BASIC, you do not require the closing quotation mark on `PRINT` or `LET` statements as the interpreter will auto-close it, this saves one BASIC token.

Alternatively, one may simply use direct mode as follows:

#### Commodore BASIC 23 PETSCII characters (+ `RETURN` to execute)

```
?"N NE E SE S SW W NW
```

I'm not sure how to count the number of bytes used in this instance as according to the interpreter `?` and `PRINT` use the same number of bytes, and there is no program stored in memory.

Comment: `PRINT` can be replaced with `?` as well, saving four bytes.

Comment: No, that's not true; `PRINT` and `?` use the same amount of BASIC tokens. I'm not counting PETSCII characters as it's not very representative of how much of the available memory is being used by the interpreter.

Comment: After all of these years I'm still learning new stuff about the Commodore. Thanks Shaun! 
https://www.c64-wiki.com/wiki/BASIC_token

Comment: Here's one I made earlier (for the C64) -> https://pastebin.com/NMYzTC7k

Answer (score 6):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 13 bytes

```
«ƛ.←√Fǎ⁰ɾ@=½•
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C2%AB%C6%9B.%E2%86%90%E2%88%9AF%C7%8E%E2%81%B0%C9%BE%40%3D%C2%BD%E2%80%A2&inputs=&header=&footer=)

-1 thanks to AaronMiller

Vyxal forever lads, it has crushed 05AB1E and Jelly I am so proud

Comment: [Why settle for a tie with 05AB1E when we can beat it?](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C2%AB%C6%9B.%E2%86%90%E2%88%9AF%C7%8E%E2%81%B0%C9%BE%40%3D%C2%BD%E2%80%A2&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Comment: I wholeheartedly approve of this

Answer (score 5):

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), 138 bytes

```
{{i}i}c{{d}}cs{i}c{d}ic{{d}}iisicsic{{d}}iisicisddddddc{d}ddddc{{d}}iisicisddddddc{{iiii}}sicisddddddciiiic{{d}d}icisddc{{d}d}ics{i}c{i}dc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY0xDsAwDAJf1EdVplWZPSLe7taJFGUoi80ZYVwnbuZzVEk0HRLsSPUKc3oyGbkbJoY6NOfPSfxk76zJyHZ302XmSxpR9QI)

So, outputting in lower-case with newlines is better than default (upper-case with spaces).

This code was generated by my optimizer, written in C++ (thanks to [squid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/85755/squid) for another optimization idea!):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>


int eval(const std::string& actions, int result)
{
    int mult = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < (int)actions.length(); ++i)
    {
        switch (actions[i])
        {
        case 's':
            result *= result;
            if (result == 256)
                result = 0;
            break;

        case '{':
            mult *= 10;
            break;

        case '}':
            mult /= 10;
            break;

        case 'd':
            if (result > 256 && result - mult <= 256)
                result = (result - mult) % 256;
            else
                result -= mult;
            break;

        case 'i':
            if (result < 256 && result + mult >= 256)
                result = (result + mult) % 256;
            else
                result += mult;
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

struct worse
{
    bool operator()(const std::string& a1, const std::string& a2)
    {
        return a1.length() > a2.length();
    }
};

std::string BestStr(int accumulator, int target)
{
    std::priority_queue<std::string, std::vector<std::string>, worse> actions;
    actions.push(std::string(""));
    while (true)
    {
        std::string a = actions.top();
        int new_acc = eval(a, accumulator);
        if (new_acc == target)
            return a + "c";

        actions.pop();

        int last_braces = 0;
        int i = a.length() - 1;
        while (i >= 0 && a[i] == '}' && last_braces < 2)
        {
            ++last_braces;
            --i;
        }
        bool is_last_i = (i >= 0 && a[i] == 'i');
        bool is_last_d = (i >= 0 && a[i] == 'd');
        bool may_add_braces = (i < 0 || a[i] == 's');
        bool may_add_c = (new_acc > 1 && new_acc < 30);

        if (may_add_c)
        {
            actions.push(a + "s");
        }
        if (may_add_braces)
        {
            actions.push(a + "{{}}");
            actions.push(a + "{}");
        }
        for (int braces_back = 0; braces_back <= last_braces; ++braces_back)
        {
            for (int c = 'd'; c <= 'i'; c += 'i' - 'd')
            {
                if ((!is_last_i || c == 'i') &&
                    (!is_last_d || c == 'd') ||
                    braces_back == 0)
                {
                    std::string new_actions = a;
                    new_actions.insert(new_actions.length() - braces_back, 1, (char)c);
                    actions.push(new_actions);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

std::string DeadfishConvert(std::string s)
{
    std::string result;
    int accumulator = 0;

    for (int c: s)
    {
        result += BestStr(accumulator, c);
        accumulator = c;
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::string s1 = DeadfishConvert("N NE E SE S SW W NW");
    std::cout << s1 << '\n';
    std::cout << s1.length() << '\n' << '\n';
    std::string s2 = DeadfishConvert("n ne e se s sw w nw");
    std::cout << s2 << '\n';
    std::cout << s2.length() << '\n' << '\n';
    std::string s3 = DeadfishConvert("N\nNE\nE\nSE\nS\nSW\nW\nNW");
    std::cout << s3 << '\n';
    std::cout << s3.length() << '\n' << '\n';
    std::string s4 = DeadfishConvert("n\nne\ne\nse\ns\nsw\nw\nnw");
    std::cout << s4 << '\n';
    std::cout << s4.length() << '\n' << '\n';
}
```

Comment: [155](https://tio.run/##bU7RCoBACPuiPipm0Z59lH27nScXFA1hcw7Vjt1O@rVlRlAUIkyCx5LOwRxQFT4t3SYwos2/w1rU8vEqhnmz8t7pl9E/UIbMGw "Deadfish~ – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 16 bytes

Returns an array of lowercase strings. The compressed string was 18 bytes but using `a` as the delimiter instead and then splitting on that worked out shorter.

```
`nÂà!Z°°nw`qa
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=YG7CFOAhBFqwsG53YHFhIA&footer=bXUgcVM) - footer formats the output.

Answer (score 4):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), <s>23</s> 22 bytes

-1 byte thanks to ngn!

```
"WNES"@5\7108085518230
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/18p3M81WMnBNMbc0MDCwMLU1NDCyNjg/38A)

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>34</s> 30 bytes

```
echo(#:3510)<;.1'NNEESESSWWNW'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/PzU5I19D2crY1NBA08Zaz1Ddz8/VNdg1ODg83C9c/f9/AA)

Comment: Galen, for J echoing the literal would be shorter.  I would love to see that beat... I haven’t managed to do it

Comment: Yes, echoing would be be 4+19 bytes. I don't have any better ideas to.

Comment: for k: if we swap `" "`<->`"W"` (`0`<->`4` in base 5), the space will be at the end and we can remove it because out-of-bounds string indexing gives a space anyway: `"WNES"@5\7108085518230`

Comment: @ngn Good design choice for the out-of-bounds string indexing resulting in a space (at least for codegolf :) )

Comment: @GalenIvanov good for top-performance databases too :) [arthur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Whitney_%28computer_scientist%29) designed k as the underlying language for [kdb+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kdb%2B)

Comment: Can you explain how the ngn/k answer works? I can't get it to work in the k interpreter that comes with q.

Comment: Nevermind, got it, you're representing the big number in base 5. ngn doesn't need the column for `5/:bla`. Neat.

Comment: @HenryHenrinson Yes, I index into the string of characters with indeces "packed" into a big number in base 5. ngn made his version of K to return as many positions as needed in the respective number base.

Comment: @HenryHenrinson \: in k4 (q), \ in k5, \ in k6, and it looks like it's gonna be \: again in k7 (shakti). my dialect is close to k6 mostly

Answer (score 4):

### Batch File, 19 bytes

*The question never stated that you had to output `N NE E SE S SW W NW` and nothing else, <s>nor that it couldn't exit due to error after doing so</s> this code only throws an error but does not exit due to it.*

```
N NE E SE S SW W NW
```

**Output**

```
>N NE E SE S SW W NW
'N' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

---

### Batch File, 25 bytes

*Only `N NE E SE S SW W NW` output with no errors or crashes.*

```
@echo N NE E SE S SW W NW
```

Comment: You could save a byte replacing cd with just quotes, like `'N NE E SE S SW W NW'` - you'll get something like:

`N NE E SE S SW W NW - command not found`

Answer (score 4):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), <s>20</s> 17 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
ÿnesw▒∙╫m+mÉîÄ╪^─
```

-3 bytes thanks to *@maxb*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P9tYXRoZ29sZv//w79uZXN34paS4oiZ4pWrbSttw4nDrsOE4pWqXuKUgP//)

**Explanation:**

```python
ÿnesw      # Push 4-char string "nesw"
           #  STACK: "nesw"
     ▒     # Split to a list of characters
           #  STACK: ["n","e","s","w"]
      ∙    # Triplicate it
           #  STACK: ["n","e","s","w"],["n","e","s","w"],["n","e","s","w"]
╫          # Rotate the top one once towards the left
           #  STACK: ["n","e","s","w"],["n","e","s","w"],["e","s","w","n"]
 m+        # Append the top two together
           #  STACK: ["n","e","s","w"],["en","se","ws","nw"]
   m       # Map the strings in the top list to:
    ÉîÄ╪   #  Rotate the string the 1-based index amount of times towards the right
           #   STACK: ["n","e","s","w"],["ne","se","sw","nw"]
^          # Zip; creating pairs with the top two lists
           #  STACK: [["n","ne"],["e","se"],["s","sw"],["w","nw"]]
 ─         # Flatten this list
           #  STACK: ["n","ne","e","se","s","sw","w","nw"]
           # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Comment: [17 bytes](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P9tYXRoZ29sZv//w79uZXN34paS4oiZ4pWrbSttw4nDrsOE4pWqXuKUgP//). This was a fun challenge. I tried it before, but ended up where you did. I think the most you could do from this is 1 byte more, but I couldn't find a shorter way.

Comment: @maxb Ah nice approach. I must admit that those code of block-size X (`É` and `Ä` in this case) still confuse me a bit sometimes.. Sometimes I'm not sure when I do or don't have to use those code-blocks. Your `m+` doesn't use one for example. But your `Ä` is a code-block of size 1. I tried `mÅî╪` just yet to see what happened, which is why I now understand why there is a code-block of size 1 `Ä` to begin with. :) ) Thanks for the -3 bytes, though. Still a lot to learn I see.

Comment: Nice explanation! I tried doing a solution without converting it to a list of chars, but the zip command was a bit wonky. For the code blocks, think of them as replacements, used instead of `{}`. `mÅî╪` creates the mapping, but it doesn't have a for-loop inside the mapping. If you write `m{î{╪}}`, it is perhaps easier to see that the code is "map to: loop <index> times, and rotate the string each loop". The reason why `m+` does not have one is that certain commands have implicit 1-byte blocks (map, filter, reduce, etc), but `î` is not a command meant to be used in combination with a block.

Comment: @maxb I indeed knew the code-blocks were a shorter variant of `{...}`, but I kinda forgot `integer{` is a for-loop. :) Now the `îÄ╪` makes a lot more sense. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 4):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 151 bytes

```
[S S S T    T   N
_Push_3_W][S S T    T   T   S N
_Push_-6_N][S S T   T   T   S T S S N
_Push_-52_space][S S S T    T   N
_Push_3_W][S T  S S T   N
_Copy_0-based_1st_(space)][S S S T  T   N
_Push_3_W][S S T    T   N
_Push_-1_S][S T S S T   S N
_Copy_0-based_2nd_(space)][S S T    T   N
_Push_-1_S][S T S S T   N
_Copy_0-based_1st_(space)][S S T    T   T   T   T   N
_Push_-15_E][S S T  T   N
_Push_-1_S][S T S S T   S N
_Copy_0-based_2nd_(space)][S T  S S T   S N
_Copy_0-based_2nd_(E)][S T  S S T   N
_Copy_0-based_1st_(space)][S T  S S T   N
_Copy_0-based_1st_(E)][S S T    T   T   S N
_Push_-6_N][S T S S T   S N
_Copy_0-based_2nd_(space)][S S T    T   T   S N
_Push_-6_N][N
S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP][S S S T S T S T S S N
_Push_84][T S S S _Add][T   N
S S _Print_as_character][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##VU1bCoAwDPtOTpGrDRnon6Dg8Wu7Dtb1owl5kO@83v7c7ehmkgDGgyZAwYbsFFyRFMTNRNxuF6gx1b4D55ByE8ok3TH7AQ) (with raw spaces, tabs, and new-lines only).

**Explanation:**

1. Push the unicode values minus constant 84 for the characters "WN W WS S ES E EN N" to the stack (note that the string is pushed in reversed). In addition, I use a few copies of previously pushed values to save bytes where possible.
2. Then start an infinite loop, which does the following:

   1. Add the constant 84 to the current unicode value
   2. Print it as character to STDOUT

The constant `84` is generated by [this Java program which I wrote for another challenge I answered in Whitespace](https://tio.run/##fVLva9swEP3ev@K4TxJKTQYrY3ZEaSEfDEs@zNky6MqQXTVR58iedA6Ekb89k2s7P7ZRMBK@9@7p7t69qK26fnn6eTgUpfIeZsrY31cAdZOXpgBPisK1rcwTbALEMnLGrh4eQfGWBtAFwGnflAQS1MP4MXlFjCXwG1WW2rdAakmvtItmd99@fL379GU6glR@uEnOVQb650ENscOfK8daPSPTxEze3YwTI0RfwakGiTiiUS2HrC4v35GGPO4qjFaa7kPAM35MByAZxBfVcm0CUqtC3xur3K7TZfm14cmR6ySjSP9qVOlZzW8xm3@3GcbEhTuRaknDz76/zTNzUantitaMw@TY61kZ/7R/png2yZPMCU5D3Fw@2Z3ZzpPeRFVDUR26odIy7NIlikFUYBJGiyIVCDGgeGsaKe@f/VuZXZb/ytpfhaNfot6lt7Rbi20/kK1ywRfMMhTMTsa3uMAYM@SXC1HEw15RdSHVonymaB2p3DPL@f@cJyGLyfuPwcSgvei3ppub09Q4GxgY/MWul/3hcJjDfApTyMIH2RKWMF/@AQ).

Answer (score 4):

## [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/How_CSS_works), <strike>42</strike> 39 bytes

(thanks to a stone arachnid for the revised version)

```css
body:after{content:"N NE E SE S SW W NW"
```

Comment: -3 bytes: `body:after{content:"N NE E SE S SW W NW"`

Comment: Oh I forgot, that's valid as well ofc, updated :)!

Answer (score 4):

### Python2, 59 bytes

```python
''.join(' SEWN'[0xe0619042210504>>i*3&7]for i in range(19))
```

The magic number is the joined three-bit indexes into the character string, reverse order so we can start iterating at the LSB.

---

I spent a while trying to shrink the magic number, but repeating the character string via multiply to allow for extra indexes doesn't work out due to needing to encode for space - best I got for overlapping indexes in the lookup added more characters to the string than digits removed from the magic number (including a couple of unfortunate don't-cares in the middle):

```python
''.join('WN S ES W xxE '[0x423659711>>i*2&15]for i in range(19))
```

Comment: Why make ir simple when you can make it complicated? :-)

Answer (score 4):

## [Seed](https://github.com/TryItOnline/seed), 4251 bytes

```
27 860147400464320299851319650217038525067593962313164914063802148270004754537839527004961550644011737763173154284403302082858336215121754817673301632815648307157082257250065969906234717399421909542980478171410880440751722628315229816701382847058322399070856858731820592153559264698086256217073752803742509491363133456184161014315870765856600563476019957791284745304281660469000032221201987453977657076508857068925011334779959071440923984103143261670811286681623926107584024737407335854701183247862900875519132553862748352119660143037154122195573484790384903915970480907443474210394470962277045139788233096906291178764592241041611441485846755897013873688521530706196990820905883449849751950542262212135591408570969484383431331268013190679834203987004737033313790768284011421240552315405082211961547940945234054982540700959040110356065461918175100640645479538002873406489037076456708483336597830606103157984606500496104240680721715484975347636031339682884674007607761345031515356027627047153497243272493312777270059024405453326103645777154783737896705880974153479385405461479666492424804798913240004709514175124491345454890697719341525477491425506610736434419234873135671474320918887316021471114682305222060888267915897813615746066948876815582512745575223896397735870135010211620878858423461465501063112149784622948077561122339504363312618787910627004536262109268282720077104133896334152799286447973176850047049812237713119532715197762392242720792955229362464454600594810210467053711629390655097050460183390576348650022884751999375732126411381491754798404626390434531750738731272129720457996733567288607018123496287262160638316644435886734080491415247676750503867190420441091488618537213370224085728523393619833129203818082398409724941259872470927203359894330981108281123358998365863404548111735330153890675493224241792528725858340777392950394427682710593902374005599390211202010183187773313755391636819970533772133030396082626453690202239163311449200997783715732798122360869214085295495205587704852617986211913577714214894103975695818432639029127400486966542504511176639066696550158657913890844890562994316733022295096182193874563287743954751083012315029203163625022641203785665910088174692911838388292883069099394602294401738461660317279173837890672723734359376951296954419885743000344118132620159094589745339998487533132912807955511930376108281742417048694994875241588696652295801421718174803743124679206340225332097286300793979362905965159380929127793048151559525010844247959055728814555227894949967607223815007539935866407118545974733499467978719520674830213387424230607171033962289851248037814785709294099111079872519162461838713157037955879646633307327632199374397038125921466729486072989316466253855183888968132751168378559192389783877180105811003888702407695849761551983252272136707803738209259164664868613103576660297351725095830903937947897824922994115970348394937807639806260540922571073766242821778449979029518064508677282684721476618711020644303120169502947696562952368545317073951472329943172059804905148953167123224802341970130868655853508010679907291864781248708382895527072805076419959404999796416487609739366680312473571591439396203866000938847930213950479915383946224278267661324765517520245110902687465374197341697248788763795723636008536927460160699589679376204284666762952828550700427849440153722541367837884874936070390103822579251528194036368492691743157507007441316773257650566047289586030443027248477537583575486086849301248855085404298181531070581096279202982969807660922182894833612275870735415456262697094185364902898042294060753067768982931035992143317507864980963267558535182176412835015890947861515892664431426681784697668827491173215527175448012211609218424524444896026378969503208454034161694651869812191979848741948472549690935926453753636695759524608297815672107532614104226930403335546065437317024985496835938364395583613835089520335424746078337656399280976500954797578444275697683434911793855960947914672558887185471712327031861804193341374816922655961374046504439546326688852794774993974104827407822683150065349462048012229814913150474813478266062076194247990327161206357488393540333896367735722260126440026734314269599013734005627347044302569936610219118261640990110423736786326407200834287772995647774230547965
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JdeHbSA5EATAVC4E2iGZz18Elz/01SsIkLSOHNNm@O/v3/9@fsb5c6v1dVZrq9Ycbbx3d5/91W6jnzbvHrvV2W@@GtOTWq@vVvN6vu44zadnrz3PnW/ner3q20drtd7PPKemP32vcd2as412x913zhp9d9vsdfup41GvOW7fte5sp@/jzbGPEFrtV@81QaxjuffW6K89q74rAgv01dv1/2pn9zNGjWvX4Xmv0/q06TrNvmP4vFl7lzCEdkfbTyxz@1OrrHhr7EoFJLDHbfMsUTzJT@nMuXb1u3p15bPL9WJtC1Zru4SorO/tc17PrsrTpN89trqSNUGMPrx08/Ap0v6WkIF/6j679exjibdF2@X1BG7TNu05Klndbv0qK3vkltTvamOJWhnmFJKce5e0GtWw9z17d2mMvac7R6n36DoeJEyJ6lQX3Nv7zCX4BwXLr9f3O23dJpq1RKYD7i4bwMY4noHOO/cOndQtzXoQcE8tdR0CT8EkAjjChKp939eZM0ve6YC2VP86rSlPt@5cS9JPT99u2q2vKtfTK0BMtbwuzunNdKaPui0QBtvn3hDjDSzVBPq8IqNTQYPCyGGstvcIQNsO3lILF@cp@PLAbREMj62SXuS7NnfB5BJsh73dIRQtVr5T19aGpHLjqlw6CzDapdhgr47w7fu0cotyZa1f5sCJz247wCeKL/PgaVZLdi@Bp3YoC2Rw02ExywS@1cbRUrm68uWAE79eqnLOCTvFP1ZS2jMYalNkHiXhO5XovgpJdPmsLHIeDcj7RSeABP@HEMO5dwOj9SmAwuCfOlj8JSQ/Ui/I7m9aSf3OiXaMaEOQame97UC9QkLRn0gRFVLSm1sVjTldl2Q9Gy4PVfNsaG0PeC46qmDqFxCAGvXYmiXfBcA@mTIKwWZIapfWrYoviHADQ9tLrXYeoDZoKZwKEw5ZnoPo6KDyuy3cD766TwXQ6pO7TcdIBXamN@qtMydYn9/WX/JIjKeo8qQlyP3VDKyytLftCzZDG3q0IGRWZUudNxBRLDYh0aoahRFZsiAmeoWx0iHQLUkglEBxGdLwB3DWDbZGYBMSvUfRzoT7WhTmSjcKHBT6bqiVPCXlph6lDeLoA5ikKo/otFZZDvxs0xUQ/@9JESrOoHEiXQp@KySAFX1XBTD2g8UURbNtZE2y4KlX@5UKYqOL5MNsLpHCazEii@Ph8u3E@dPBFnw/WrXxewSCKZjg4HJFgYhjnEb7IoScDfOuerRgs8ebdiwHXaMVSD5TdCgmvslnx6SwHnbShU/rRpRDd2OIbURlicf7LuzD2noqDyA@itQQ2cfUwPKlM5L7Umx@HiirWQVAPm@xpR6AUUiZNh@Ekj3NOr9I8UUxqhRHQIvf2v1Ged0ogRP0HnH/KL3i0C9@QUPqbaWLbyTWF37AoOWKijEb2q0iladI/j4@qJaO99SHdfvNEhmv/sarsVFRSNZlFjM@FvNGclQJ0hqN69HV9jUuVbDPCOxcnpglCWdI9JMrxisu8GA3rkQf2bvCwnKoSHShEVUrQkjKXq6jV3qn8bQL4mBbopDid7QlbsrU@K0rWJW@FtFAyk4@IoIIQZaJrHalLjiPcarxYob1C6Hz4eKr11IBr7sOvlO@1IHlrCh2Xv2mBXDFTokHcIaYGV2D6BINTX0njFZRlRYPx3hfU9y2S9R8v4xePZUfMRXvhhH4uiMIEl@JpeICUTl15v7SgXX8MzEgFOM9jG8maNGQrR7QVFy/BYg3mY2YkakKUjLmjZshcHx52O58Hjtih1pEuEO3jBBRpLQs8uWVmbrRRQMUFHNysIWIHsGBiQyT4SpQlo4pYgLH1cyUBRp8Zme5SzXTKRDqlQ7H6V90/GQzNVaVHXK3vEwtJBt40@1MnhGLkQrJjz6epDEzTdj828rO1GbGwwEevIhyJkZgRviWUUcu8rYhhRnBfP@GH1oKkJ4CCaZcDlCs0dKm1Fia9ZQTIVAXi3XZ6rLKZIC7yI/ydDi@VvERWYyMyrCWcVAaPvAMLMCD/FWaOL9BNBYL6L8UPJlZo6xth@U7pMS2kbZR5P4NVi2ZaorRoKVqIPBS9M6LtNa7ZpIMxvEYWwD/zqyS2VW/JfDST1XjrOAbLTZtJlaoknJmsPmdDSLprKmBcmbGD12xTDtGYcPjz9Li3TLPPCoyJkP4oj3KrjKEgAkkeilUBD4urdawJfVMQbSPXo54fuxGpBlZQvyRGVt/bZDS5ZCxM7Nl1/UpSAzGIBJcBFjhvW7Gx8gePHynDTjhVQTbYSXKDQFFbDLmn289028OQhTe27w1U7/GKCJIo69mZupSBnw0kCvUDtpv1oomcjuRZazK6YVm6F7L1NUzSUc03I6GBWYVdPX0KMNjsYHzHTemPEAjs4dCEbT4p@mshb4WDmEriqDrTCsLfpB/YeD8tXcw8K4hZXzDOJhEzAMAZ6fPAKKUXosgOZPE1x0@Rk4cmZEQzuA@Mtf1jBRBUYYJGMwRoid2pqPBxsI4CLLVN2PGTo1gnLil03qt82AZnyMt73yiDAgpo5blOEHZ3meXktIYa5yI5IqPZhTMVJITUObaHDZYTdQ0Q//e34i9ZsYvgCNwlrwxjJs5NMqltjNZ3yikTyK7voIU2OJtGeFwIMNUDI6nhuPAtVOHnD6@MmRepuqpG3IIydIgHDGOxKIotPWMO0bEl/EQ4B3gdLnyYS4NYjs4sk96o8Y3M@Q3Qcc7kl3KLjhf5ZibA7L9V0jwFT/AyiTew0Hrm@RRTxHMlOapz1MonX6BFJPik0xXib96ZXANwJHOBi2zonFhZJz7@k8eECaem/Pu8Pf84l4tohGZTuPnOaXGN3JiWvFoxEtGIjfh5HSWSYmiOfL7J06U0tb@@fkf)

Comment: [-1724 bytes](https://ghostbin.com/D7bOp).

Comment: @awi I golfed it with my current generator even further. now my solution is 20 bytes smaller than yours.

Comment: now 40 bytes smaller.

Comment: How long does it take for your generator to find these solutions? Mine takes 1-10 minutes.

Comment: @awi around a minute.

Answer (score 4):

## [Hodor](https://github.com/hummingbirdtech/hodor), 177 bytes

```
hodor.hod("HoOodoOorhodor  HoOodoOorhodor HooodorrHodor  HooodorrHodor  HODOR?!? HooodorrHodor  HODOR?!?  HODOR?!? Hooodorrhodor  Hooodorrhodor  HoOodoOorhodor Hooodorrhodor ");
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8hPyS/6/z8DROkBSQ0lj3x/IMc/vwgspqCAxvfIzwfRRR4wWVSuv4t/kL2iPU5xTBUZqAbhtxXCU9K0/v8fAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 14 bytes

```
.•2Àβ‡yÞJŒ¾oÒ8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f71HDIqPDDec2PWpYWHl4ntfRSYf25R@eZAEU/v8fAA)

This prints out the string except lowercase.

Comment: Just remove the final `•` for -1

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 18 bytes

```
"NeSw"it;?↺₍h₂a₀oụ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATUAyv9icmFjaHlsb2cy/@KGsOKCgeG2oP8iTmVTdyJpdDs/4oa64oKNaOKCgmHigoBv4bul////Wg)

Semi-port of [my Jelly solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226044/85334). [Generates](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/10753#10753) each direction.

```
"NeSw"                Let the input variable be "NeSw".
      i               Take a pair [element, 0-index] from it,
       t              extract the index,
        ;?↺₍          and rotate the input variable left by that many places.
            h₂        Keep only the first two elements of the rotation,
              a₀      take a prefix (nonempty, shortest first) of it,
                o     sort (putting uppercase before lowercase),
                 ụ    and fold to uppercase.
```

Barely beats my original...

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 19 bytes

```
"NNEESESSWWNW"ḍ₄ḍᵐc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/X8nPz9U12DU4ODzcL1zp4Y7eR00tQPLh1gnJ////jwIA)

Outputs as a list. `ḍ₄ḍᵐc` saves two bytes over writing out seven spaces and making the entire predicate a string literal, so at least it ties PHP...

```
"NNEESESSWWNW"         The string "NNEESESSWWNW"
              ḍ₄       split into quarters
                 ᵐ     with each quarter
                ḍ      split in half
                  c    and concatenated
                       is the output.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [JSFuck](http://www.jsfuck.com/), 8529 bytes

```
[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+((+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]])+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]])()([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+([]+[])[(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]]]+((![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]]+(+[![]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]]+(+[![]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+!+[]])[(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+((+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]((!![]+[])[+[]])[([][(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]](([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[+[]])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+[+[]]]+![]+(![]+[+[]])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+[+[]]])()[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((![]+[+[]])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+[+[]]])+[])[+!+[]])+([]+[])[(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]]])())
```

Just for the fun of it

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 21 bytes

```powershell
'N NE E SE S SW W NW'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X91Pwc9VwVUhGIgUgsMVwhX8wtX//wcA)

Comment: Same in Swift Playground, with `"N NE E SE S SW W NW"`, if you want. But too trivial to post.

Comment: this is `code golf`. see `not trivial` in the edit history.

Answer (score 2):

## Assembly (x86, Linux), 68 bytes

```
$ od -x a
0000000 457f 464c 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0500
0000020 0002 0003 001b 0500 001b 0500 0004 0000
0000040 13b2 31b9 0000 cd05 2580 0020 0001 cd40
0000060 4e80 4e20 2045 2045 4553 5320 5320 2057
0000100 2057 574e
0000104
$ ./a
N NE E SE S SW W NW$
```

Source:

```
BITS 32
org 0x05000000
db 127,"ELF"
dd 1,0
dd $$
dw 2,3
dd 0x0500001B,0x0500001B
dd 4
mov dl,19
mov ecx,m
int 128
db 37
dw 32,1
inc eax
int 0x80
m db 'N NE E SE S SW W NW'
```

Code mostly taken from [Shortest ELF for "Hello world\n"?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5696/shortest-elf-for-hello-world-n)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-s`, 20 bytes

Just *barely* shorter than printing the literal string.

```
"NESW"WV<>"NESESWNW"
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgWbSSbrFS7IKlpSVpuhZblPxcg8OVwsNs7EAsINsvXAkiBVWxAEoDAA)

#### Explanation

```
"NESW"WV<>"NESESWNW"
      WV              Weave
"NESW"                the characters of this string
                      with
          "NESESWNW"  this string
        <>            taken in blocks of 2 characters each
                      Result: ["N";"NE";"E";"SE";"S";"SW";"W";"NW"]
                      Autoprint, space-separated (-s flag)
```

I added the unary version of `<>` because of this challenge, although I'm sure it will be useful elsewhere too.

Answer (score 2):

## A0A0, 69 bytes

```
P78P32P83
P32P83P87
P78P69P32
P69P32P87
P32P83P32
P69P32P78
G-6G-6P87
```

Not much to this one, `Px` prints the character corresponding to ascii value `x`, so we just print the correct values. `G-6` jumps back to the top. Splitting the code into three columns is optimal for saving bytes on new lines, while not using too many bytes on additional jumps. Two columns gives the same amount of bytes, but three columns is nicer to display on this site.

Answer (score 2):

## [Malbolge](https://github.com/TryItOnline/malbolge), <s>151</s> <s>126</s> <s>118</s> 115 bytes

```
(&<`@#!\}5Y9z1Uv4tQsr)M-n%I#"!&DBe/R-`_<ts[Jp$5WUk1ShmPkd*uts%G#bE`lkW\>-Y+:utT`R5P2HMk/-h++@d'&%;:^8~6}Y32V0T.uQ+N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y03MScrPSU/9/19DzSbBQVkxptY00rLKMLTMpCSwuEjTVzdP1VNZSVHNxSlVP0g3Id6mpDjaq0DFNDw02zA4IzcgO0WrtKRY1V05yTUhJzs8xk43UtuqtCQkIcg0wMjDN1tfN0Nb2yFFXU3V2irOos6sNtLYKMwgRK80UNvv/38A)

Comment: Well done! (Fill)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 bytes

```
“æṖØq’ḃ⁴ḃ4ị“NESW
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5zDyx7unHZ4RuGjhpkPdzQ/atwCJE0e7u4GSvm5Bof//w8A)

[With footer to print separated by space](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5zDyx7unHZ4RuGjhpkPdzQ/atwCJE0e7u4GSvm5BocDlcz1/g8A)

A niladic link which returns a list of strings. 2 bytes shorter (and arguably more interesting) than the compressed string in Jelly.

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 24 bytes

Quick, gotta do it before anyone else

```java
v->"N NE E SE S SW W NW"
```

[Null is equivalent to no input](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12681/52210)
[TIO](https://tio.run/##JYyxCoMwGIT3PMXhlAz6AtJuutUlUIfSIVUjsTGK@Q0U8dnTlMLBDfd9N6mg8ql/x84q73FTxuFgzDgaNq26AfUhaTNuhOb3xfQIojwZW/eXNR08KUoVfsOcVP5nH0@obfQiPdXQuMSQX7MGTYUKMgWyRYumzWLJ5MfTMBfLTsWaXLKO60Jzt1srRMnOM34B)

Comment: [According to the meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12681/52210) it indeed is allowed to take an unused `null` argument when a challenge states no input. I suggest using the `Void` class as input, since it has no useful static calls nor purposes. [Try it online.](https://tio.run/##JYyxCoMwGIT3PMXhlAz6AtJuutUlUIfSIVUjsTGK@Q0U8dnTlMLBDfd9N6mg8ql/x84q73FTxuFgzDgaNq26AfUhaTNuhOb3xfQIojwZW/eXNR08KUoVfsOcVP5nH0@obfQiPdXQuMSQX7MGTYUKMgWyRYumzWLJ5MfTMBfLTsWaXLKO60Jzt1srRMnOM34B) EDIT: Ah, I see you had that initially, so you could roll-back and perhaps add the meta-post. ;)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I rolled it back

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 24 bytes

```cs
_=>"N NE E SE S SW W NW"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9Wmpdsk5@UlZpcolNcUpSZl26XZvs/3tZOyU/Bz1XBVSEYiBSCwxXCFfzClf5bc4UXZZakaqRpGGhqWv8HAA)

Comment: This also works in Javascript.

Comment: Polyglot with Foo.

Comment: what other characters are allowed besides '_' ?

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 26 bytes

```r
cat('N NE E SE S SW W NW')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxREPdT8HPVcFVIRiIFILDFcIV/MLVNf//BwA)

Answer (score 1):

As input to Commodore BASIC, you can get it even shorter: (23 bytes)

```
0 ?"N NE E SE S SW W NW
```

**?** is shorthand for **PRINT**.

Comment: `?` and `PRINT` use the same number of BASIC tokens so you are not saving any memory in your stored symbolic listing.

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>25</s> 24 bytes

This is a pretty simple answer. Push the string in reverse, then print the stack. Exits with an error due to stack underflow.

```
"WN W WS S ES E EN N">o<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/XyncTyFcITxYIVjBFYgUXP0U/JTs8m3@/wcA)

Comment: You can remove the skip and it still works, doesn't it?

Comment: @squid Indeed. I originally was using `|` instead of the arrows.

Comment: If superfluous spaces are allowed, you can shave off one more byte `"WN WWS SES EEN N">ooa<`.

Comment: @PidgeyUsedGust https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/186582/print-n-ne-e-se-s-sw-w-nw/186704?noredirect=1#comment447191_186582

Answer (score 1):

## [Assembly (MIPS, SPIM)](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spim), <strike>71</strike> 70 bytes

```
.data
t:.ascii"N NE E SE S SW W NW"
.text
main:li $2,4
la $4,t
syscall
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcIxCsAgDADAPa8I4igOxcnd1cXBObQdArEUkqF9fdrj9Oblng8yAquZdGcOHXvDhuOPY@LEPgNkOx@DRXxVYYxbKiCEsSQDfXUnEfcP)

I haven't done anything with MIPS in a while, so if there's a shorter way please tell me!

Edit: used an ascii and not an asciiz string

Answer (score 1):

## k, 23 bytes

```
1_,/'$,/``N`S,/:\:``E`W
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg/), 19 bytes

Simply hard-coding the answer.

```
N NE E SE S SW W NW
```

Answer (score 1):

## SQL, <strike>28</strike> 26 bytes

On behalf of BradC:

```
PRINT'N NE E SE S SW W NW'
```

<strike>SELECT 'N NE E SE S SW W NW'</strike>

Comment: You can save 2 bytes with `PRINT'N NE E SE S SW W NW'`

Comment: @BradC: Also thought about this, but I am not sure it matches the rules, because, yes, it prints desired result, but in principle returns nothing. But you may be right.

Comment: We pretty routinely use whichever of `PRINT` or `SELECT` is shorter/more useful for SQL-language challenges on CodeGolf, see [the SQL language tips thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/118743/70172). Either way you can drop the space before the quote.

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
Ä\8←ΘåÑ¥▒Nx╚ø┼Çt
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8e5c381be986a59db14e78c800c58074&i=&a=1)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), [21 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9X1CUmVeioORQHf3fxk@h2k9HJ7jWVSFYoTpYR8evNtzuf2yt0n8A)

```perl
<N {N,,S}E S {S,,N}W>
```

Standard `glob` function emulating *nix shell. See [`perldoc -f glob`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob) for more details.

#### Alternative, 21 bytes

```perl
<N NE E SE S SW W NW>
```

Didn't need to use `qw` since `glob` splits on whitespace and treats each pattern separately.

Comment: This doesn’t appear to be in the correct order

Comment: I thought [your comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/186582/print-n-ne-e-se-s-sw-w-nw/225999?noredirect=1#comment447027_186582) alluded to relaxing that requirement

Comment: It’s a bit confusing, but read the last two sentences of the comment and it should be clear.

Comment: The first part of that was referring to a now deleted comment about disallowing snippets

Comment: How is this 14 bytes?

Comment: Not sure how that happened, fixed

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 bytes

```
8ḶHị“eSwN”Ṣ€Œu
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AScA2P9qZWxsef//OOG4tkjhu4vigJxlU3dO4oCd4bmi4oKsxZJ1/8KiS/8)

Niladic link returning a list of strings.

```
  H               Halve
8Ḷ                each number in 0 .. 7,
   ị“eSwN”        and modular 1-index each into “eSwN”.
                  Not only is ị modular, but it also handles fractional indices by flooring and ceiling them, returning a list of both elements.
          Ṣ€      Sort each, placing lowercase letters after uppercase.
            Œu    Uppercase.
```

<s>Come to think of it, this returns a ragged array of characters, rather than a real list of strings, so I guess you can slap a `K` on the end and call it a full program if that’s an issue.</s> I guess the `Ṣ` actually does wrap non-list arguments.

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
“£ḂA⁷<ọŒ⁼Ẓ2Ẏ®
```

Simple compressed string. Add the `Ụ` flag if you want it in uppercase.

##### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 21 bytes

I don't think it gets any shorter than this in Haskell.

```hs
"N NE E SE S SW W NW"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzX8lPwc9VwVUhGIgUgsMVwhX8wpX@5yZm5inYKhSUlgSXFCmk/f@XnJaTmF78XzfCOSAAAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 22 bytes

```ruby
p'N NE E SE S SW W NW'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0DdT8HPVcFVIRiIFILDFcIV/MLV//8HAA)

Answer (score 0):

One more Python example:

```
for i in range(8):print''.join(c*((i+m)%8<3)for c,m in zip('NSEW',(1,5,7,3))),
```

I tried to use no cryptic operations, just normal math + boolean logic.
[Try it](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/Py2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw0LTqqAoM69EXV0vKz8zTyNZS0MjUztXU9XCxlgTpDZZJxekuiqzQEPdL9g1XF1Hw1DHVMdcx1hTU1Pn/38A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
Æ+góïr!½*ÄJ╓╨°╩Æ
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=922b67a28b7221ab2a8e4ad6d0f8ca92&i=&a=1)

Answer (score 0):

## Assembly (x86, GCC), 151 bytes

```
$ cat foo.s
.global _start
.text
_start:mov $1,%rax
mov $1,%rdi
mov $m,%rsi
mov $19,%rdx
syscall
mov $60,%rax
xor %rdi,%rdi
syscall
m:.ascii "N NE E SE S SW W NW"
$ gcc -c foo.s && ld foo.o && ./a.out
N NE E SE S SW W NW$
```

Comment: Suggest `mov $60,%al`

Comment: `lea` can save you some `$`. (e.g. `lea 1,%eax`)

Answer (score 0):

## **DC, 79 bytes**

```
78sn7Dss69se87swAsblblwlnlblwlblwlslblslblelslblelblelnlblnPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP
```

It loads the characters NESW and newline into registers, then loads them onto the stack and prints them all

Answer (score 0):

## [Underload](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Underload), 22 bytes

```
(N NE E SE S SW W NW)S
```

Pretty self explanatory

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K81LSS3KyU9M@f9fw0/Bz1XBVSEYiBSCwxXCFfzCNYP//wcA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 45 bytes

```
"WN W":" "\"S":" "\" ES E":" "\"N":" "\>:#,_@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/XyncTyFcyUpJQSlGKRhKK7gGK7hC2X4Q2s5KWSfe4f9/AA)

Comment: Or just [hardcode the string](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/XyncTyFcITxYIVjBFYgUXP0U/JTsrJR14h3@/wcA)

Comment: @JoKing I am aware that this is an option, but I didn't want to just hardcode it

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 26 bytes

```python
print'N NE E SE S SW W NW'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69E3U/Bz1XBVSEYiBSCwxXCFfzC1f//BwA)

Why make things complicate when we can do simple??

Answer (score 0):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 25 bytes

```
prin"N NE E SE S SW W NW"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhId@7@gKDNPyU/Bz1XBVSEYiBSCwxXCFfzClf7/BwA)

My first Red answer and first answer this month.

Comment: Already beating your python answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

## Smalltalk, 37 bytes

```
Transcript show:'N NE E SE S SW W NW'
```

26 bytes if you don't mind surrounding quotes:

```
'N NE E SE S SW W NW'print
```